# Making VMs work in a private network in virtualbox

Tags: networking, linux, virtualization

I've been trying out DHCP to work in virtualbox to assign IPs to VMs in hostonly networking or any other method that could do the job.
Unfortunately I don't have wired modem right now, I'm using mobile internet connection to provide NAT connectivity to VMs.
The **Kali VM** that can be logged onto gets IP from NAT & it can use internet. The other **VM** is from Vulnhub for pentesting purpose and I can't login to it to make any manual changes in it's networking.
I assigned two adapters to Kali VM- **NAT** and **Host-only**. 
NAT assignment to Kali is working but I can't see other adapter which was supposed to be visible for **host-only adapter**.
So I'm sure that IP assignment to Vulnhub VM is not working either.
When I see IFCONFIG output in host Mint machine, **vboxnet0** adapter is present there.

> ```
> vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
> inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
> ```

**The IPv4 address** for vboxnet0 adapter in VirtualBox is **192.168.56.1/24**
DHCP server parameters are as follows:-

> server address     : 192.168.56.1 
> subnet mask        : 255.255.255.0
>   Lower address bound: 192.168.56.2 
> Upper address bound:
>   192.168.56.254

I need to setup the scenario where Kali VM should be able to use internet using **NAT** and also should be part of **host-only** network.
Other VM should be part of only **host-only** network.
So Kali VM should be able to communicate with another VM.

Someone please let me know what could be the problem here.

**EDIT:** I just removed **NAT** adapter from Kali VM and let **host-only** adapter remain there, and Kali got the host-only network's IP. 
But the other VM couldn't receive any IP address with having only **host-only** adapter ON.

Comment: This is not a security question at all, but a Virtualbox networking question.

Comment: I agree schroeder , but I thought it's a good place to ask for. Anyways every security guy goes through virtualizing VMs :D

Comment: So finally I got an idea to make it work. Though not related to exact solution. I had an old netbook with me with Kali as base OS. So I connected it with PC with CAT5 cable & started DHCP server in it. And my host + both VMs got DHCP IPs. Atleast now I can run the scanning :)